# What is the limiting factor in loading images in Android?

Tags: android, andengine

So I'm getting really confused here. The designer I work with wants high-quality images (png files) for Android tablets, but the game also has smaller images for less-powerful devices. I figured that the amount of memory on the heap would be the metric to determine which set of images to use, by using `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`. That doesn't seem to be the case though. On BlueStacks it can load the high-quality images just fine, and it has around 40,000,000 bytes. The designer's Galaxy Nexus has black boxes for some of the larger images (which I understand is due to a lack of memory for loading the image), but his Galaxy Nexus has about 50,000,000 available bytes, which is even more than BlueStacks.

So what is the limiting factor? And on a related matter, how is it that there are mobile games that have impressive quality visuals, yet I can't manage to load a few images? What am I doing wrong?

To note, I am using AndEngine, and below is an example of how I'm loading the images.

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas resetTA = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 310 / d, 190 / d,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    resetTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(resetTA, this, "gfx/" + lowres + "reset.png", 1, 1);

    try
    {
        resetTA.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
        resetTA.load();
    }
    catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e)
    {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
```

One of the images that isn't loading in the Galaxy Nexus is a sprite sheet png file that's 2320x464.

Comment: Your desired file is around 4MB of heap space, and perhaps there isn't a single block of space that is 4MB: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html

Comment: in general, you should consider your memory to be extremely limited and write your code that way. Many devices simply do not have the memory even a mid-sized PC might contain.  Each app shares the memory with other apps and Android itself.  I think monitoring the runtime memory won't give you much help.     When loading, you need to make sure you have good sample size - no sense reading a 4MB image when its only going to  a thumbnail sized view.  Read efficient bitmaps in the Android guides here to get the real info - http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: In the past I've had issues with large images that were not 2^n dimensions in AndEngine. Not sure if that is still an issue in the later builds or not as I haven't used AndEngine for a few months.

Comment: You should also consider things like scale and projection. There's no need to load a high quality image if it's just going to be projected way off in the distance, a drop in image quality won't be noticeable. Only loading the exact size you need at any given moment is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two limiting factors here. First it's the heap memory. To find the available heap for your app you can use the method with the `Runtime` class, but that will tell you the maximum memory your app can use before it completely crashes. A limit that your app should respect in Android can be found this way:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
Log.d("MyTag", "Heap:  + Integer.toString(memoryClass));
```

The second is `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` value that limits the maximum dimension of a square texture for given device. This can vary, but the minimum these days seems to be 2048, therefore your textures can be as much as 2048x2048 pixels large. However the only recommendation is that the dimension must be larger than the screen dimensions and the real size is up to the manufacturer of the phone.

I think you can use the following code to find out the size:

```
int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
Log.d("MyTag", "GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: " + Integer.toString(int[0]));
```

---

The games can have impressive graphics before they split the big textures to smaller, load only what is needed and reuse as much as possible. I've made a game where some levels have 50000px wide ground by assembling it from 256x256 pieces making the game sharp even on full HD tablets. The pieces were distributed over several 2048x2048 textures.